# Screen Brightness Stuck on high on an HP dv7t laptop

Tags: 12.04, laptop, screen, brightness

I have an otherwise fully-functioning install of Ubuntu 12.04 on my HPdv7t laptop.

When I press the 'brightness buttons' on the keyboard the associated images appear on my screen to say I am increasing/decreasing the screen brightness.  When I go into "System Settings" I can move the 'brightness slider bar' up and down.

But none of that changes the fact that my screen is stuck on the highest brightness setting.

ANY clues on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. This giant 17-inch monitor is blinding, and this is making it hard to code for any length of time.

Comment: Hopefully someone can give you a workaround here, but in the mean time, you should [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: What's your graphics card ? nVIDIA, Intel, AMD ?

Comment: I have an NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) GT graphics card.

Comment: Did you install the proprietary drivers of NVIDIA (using additional drivers) or you're using the open-source nouvea module?

Comment: @SeyedMohammad I was originally using the open-source drivers, but since I noticed this problem I have switched to using the proprietary drivers.  Unfortunately, there has been no change at all.   Good thought though!  I was hoping it would work too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I own an Acer Aspire 5755g and I had the same problem with backlight of my screen. My PC has Nvidia GT540M. I read previous answers and found out that on my pc this advice works but I need to run some different command instead of

```
echo n > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

I have to change it to

```
echo 250 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

for example, where `250` is my desired backlight value.

I think it is because of hybrid graphics in notebooks like mine, so backlight is controlled through intel builtin controller.

In such case do `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` and you'll see your current value of brightness. In my case it was `976`. You can also look for a `max_brightness` file in the same directory to get an idea of the scale of values. You should be able to adjust the backlight by changing this number. Be aware that if you set it to `0` your backlight will be turned off and you won't be able to see what you're typing! If you try to set value more than maximum it just returns an error and nothing changes.

To set backlight value at startup you may be able to add a line like this

```
echo 250 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

to your `/etc/rc.local` file before the line saying `exit 0`.

If that does not work for you, you can try using `sysfsutils` instead. You may need to install the package:

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
```

and then modify the file `/etc/sysfs.conf` to add a line like this:

```
class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness = 250
```

Also we can enable hotkeys to change backlight manually in a comfortable way. I made my hotkeys scripts of scripts for Asus laptops placed in `/etc/acpi` directory. You need 2 scripts - one to increase brightness, another for decreasing, both placed in `/etc/acpi` directory. Also we need to set these scripts to trigger on hotkeys events, which can be done by changing files in the `/etc/acpi/events` directory. In my case their names and contents are:

```
/etc/acpi/events/asus-brightness-down
```

```
event=video DD03 00000087 00000000 
action=/etc/acpi/asus-brn-down.sh
```

```
/etc/acpi/events/asus-brightness-up
```

```
event=video DD03 00000086 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/asus-brn-up.sh
```

Where `/etc/acpi/asus-brn-down.sh` and `asus-brn-up.sh` are names of our scripts to decrease and increase brightness.

Contents of my `/etc/acpi/asus-brn-down.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# this is for acer aspire 5755G :)
KEYS_DIR=/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight

test -d $KEYS_DIR || exit 0

MIN=1
# i set MIN to 1 to almost turn off backlight, but you can set a better one value, 50 for examlple
MAX=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/max_brightness)
VAL=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/brightness)

VAL=$((VAL-25))

if [ "$VAL" -lt $MIN ]; then
VAL=$MIN
fi

echo $VAL > $KEYS_DIR/brightness
```

And contents of my `/etc/acpi/asus-brn-up.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# this is for acer aspire 5755G :)
KEYS_DIR=/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
test -d $KEYS_DIR || exit 0
MIN=1
MAX=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/max_brightness)
VAL=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/brightness)
# I decided to increase brightness by 25 per keypress but you can change it to 50 or even 1 if you like
    VAL=$((VAL+25))

if [ "$VAL" -gt $MAX ]; then
    VAL=$MAX
fi

echo $VAL > $KEYS_DIR/brightness
```

UPDATE: Same problem solved in Ubuntu 13.10 (additional solution found [in this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181534))

We need to create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`
with this content:

```
Section "Device"
       Identifier  "card0"
       Driver      "intel"
       Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
       BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Then reboot. Thats all ;)

Comment: This actually worked for me.  And thank God. Though I do feel like this is a woefully sad solution, and something that I imagine would be easy enough to script in the System Settings. I guess I just have such high hopes for Ubuntu.  Thank YOU though.  Great call.

Comment: Is there any good way to script this, or add it to a launcher? I do this every time I boot up my computer now and I would prefer it I could run this command with a simple double click.  The problem, of course, is that I need to be SU to execute the command.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on a T61 with Nvidia Quadro NVS 140M graphics card.

Switching the drivers from "current version [recommended]" to "version 173" solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If the command, `echo 250 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, worked for you than the following two suggestions should also work.

Some solutions have been to re-install bash, `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash` and others have been to modify grub, making the changes last through reboots, as outlined below:

1. Edit GRUB's configuration file with `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Edit the parameters following `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` between the double quotes to include `acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux  video.brightness_switch_enabled=1`, so it looks something like

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux video.brightness_switch_enabled=1"
   ```
3. Save and close the file
4. Make the change effective by running `sudo update-grub`
5. Restart your computer.

For more information, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=753012

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem (if I remember right) against most laptops, they either reset to 0 or to 10.  Either way, you can fix this issue by doing `sudo vim /etc/rc.local` and placing the following in there:

```
# n should be changed to the number.
echo n > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

If you need to find out what your favourite number is, then you should first adjust your screen and then do `sudo cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` and use that number.  ***Note: You might have trouble doing cat and echo with sudo, if you do do `sudo su` and then do it.***

Comment: This workaround isn't working for me with the same problem. I've [filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1016724) on the grounds that I understand all such bugs are considered hardware-specific so not well suited to subscribing to existing bugs on different hardware.